# Adding a computer player into tic tac toe java

Tags: java, swing, artificial-intelligence, tic-tac-toe

So I followed an online guide on making a basic tic tac toe game in java, [YouTube Video Guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ftJ66kZhdLk&list=PLSgj1MM9hDebzU4SGNPKLoEa_29OkQgSi&index=8)
(this is the guide)
and this program works for 2 human players fine however I was wondering about how I would add a computer into this program, I'm fairly new to java to any help would be appreciated

ill put the code below, main class code:

```
package tictactoe;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
* This is a simple little TicTacToe game.
*/
public class TicTacToe 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    JFrame ticTacToe = new TicTacToeFrame();
    ticTacToe.setTitle("Phantom TicTacToe Game!");
    ticTacToe.setSize(600, 600);
    ticTacToe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    ticTacToe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    ticTacToe.setVisible(true);
}
} // end class TicTacToe
```

TicTacToeFrame Code:

```
package tictactoe;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

/**
* JFrame to hold TicTacToe board.
*/
public class TicTacToeFrame extends JFrame
{
// Indicate whose turn it is
private char whoseTurn = 'X';
private boolean gameOver = false;

// Create cell grid
private Cell[][] cells = new Cell[3][3];

// Create a status label
JLabel jlblStatus = new JLabel("X's turn to play");

/**
* No-argument Constructor
*/
public TicTacToeFrame()
{
   // Panel to hold cells
   JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3, 0, 0));
   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
       for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
           panel.add(cells[i][j] = new Cell());

   panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red, 1));
   jlblStatus.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.yellow, 1));

   add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   add(jlblStatus, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
 }

 /**
 * Determine if game board is full.
 * @return True, if game board is full. Otherwise, false.
 */
 public boolean isFull()
 {
   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
       for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
           if (cells[i][j].getToken() == ' ')
               return false;
   return true;
 }

 /**
 * Determines if a given token has won.
 * @param token Token to test for winning
 * @return True, if the token has won. Otherwise, false.
 */
 public boolean isWon(char token)
 {
   // check rows
   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
       if ((cells[i][0].getToken() == token)
               && (cells[i][1].getToken() == token)
               && (cells[i][2].getToken() == token)) 
       {
           return true;
       }

   // check columns
   for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
       if ((cells[0][j].getToken() == token)
           && (cells[1][j].getToken() == token)
           && (cells[2][j].getToken() == token))
       {
           return true;
       }
   // check diagonal
   if ((cells[0][0].getToken() == token)
           && (cells[1][1].getToken() == token)
           && (cells[2][2].getToken() == token))
       {
           return true;
       }

   if ((cells[0][2].getToken() == token)
           && (cells[1][1].getToken() == token)
           && (cells[2][0].getToken() == token))
       {
           return true;
       }

   return false;
 }

/**
* Defines a cell in a TicTacToe game board.
*/
public class Cell extends JPanel
{
   // token of this cell
   private char token = ' ';

   /**
    * Constructor
    */
   public Cell()
   {
       setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 1));
       addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener());
   }

   /**
    * Gets the token of the cell.
    * @return The token value of the cell.
    */
   public char getToken()
   {
       return token;
   }

   /**
    * Sets the token of the cell.
    * @param c Character to use as token value.
    */
   public void setToken(char c)
   {
       token = c;
       repaint();
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
   {
       super.paintComponent(g);

       if (token == 'X')
       {
           g.drawLine(10, 10, getWidth() - 10, getHeight() - 10);
           g.drawLine(getWidth() - 10, 10, 10, getHeight() - 10);
       }

       else if (token == 'O')
       {
           g.drawOval(10, 10, getWidth() - 20, getHeight() - 20);
       }
   }

   private class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter
   {
       @Override
       public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
       {
           if (gameOver)
               return;

           // if the cell is empty and the game is not over
           if (token == ' ' && whoseTurn != ' ')
               setToken(whoseTurn);

           // Check game status
           if (isWon(whoseTurn))
           {
               jlblStatus.setText(whoseTurn + " won! Game over!");
               whoseTurn = ' ';
               gameOver = true;
           }
           else if (isFull())
           {
               jlblStatus.setText("Tie game! Game over!");
               whoseTurn = ' ';
               gameOver = true;
           }
           else
           {
               whoseTurn = (whoseTurn == 'X') ? 'O' : 'X';
               jlblStatus.setText(whoseTurn + "'s turn.");
           }
       }
   } // end class MyMouseListener
} // end class Cell
} // end class TicTacToeFrame
```

Thanks again

Comment: First thing I'd do if this were my project would be to try to separate the logic out from the view -- in other words the brains of the program from the GUI portion. If I didn't do this, and then tried to add AI to the program, I'd end up with a huge God-class, and that would be a monster to debug. I'd then work on the logic classes, and try to refactor them so that even before I added AI, it was set up so that AI would be easy to add, meaning it had classes for Player, for Board, for Cells, for Game, and these classes had "states", non-static fields, and "behaviors", non-static methods...

Comment: Tic tac toe is actually sufficiently trivial such that you can hard-code all optimal moves in advance for the AI to at least never lose. You don't need any true "AI" for it.